# Best practices for creating a "debug mode" variable for my app?

Tags: javascript, debugging, global-variables

I was about to comment out blocks of code that just printed/console.logged debugging info, and I thought, why don't I create a global scope "debug" variable, and instead of commenting this code out, put an `if (DEBUG == 1) {}` around it?

The reason I ask is because I'm working with javascript at the moment, and my code is spread across a few .js files. If I create a DEBUG variable in app.js, I'll need to export it from app.js and require it in other files; is this consistent with best practices? Is there a better way to do what I'm thinking of?

Comment: For debugging, use breakpoints. For logging, use a logging library whose logger you can dynamically enable/disable (or: change log level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Most logging libraries will have *levels* that allow you to only output or see messages whose levels are above some minimum. Alternatively, if you're just using console.log or console.debug and content to keep those in lieu of more robust log streams, you can change the behavior of these by using your own logging library; for example, if you have a debug.js file that exports your `debug()` function, import/require it once in each other file and just call `debug()` instead of `console.debug()` (or you can actually reassign `console.debug = debug` but that will have potential side effects in any dependencies or dependent code).

In `debug.js`, your function can simply check an environment variable (in node.js or similar) or global variable (in the browser) or even a hard-coded flag, and immediately return (doing nothing) if you're in production or not in the mood to print debug messages.

Take a look at bunyan's log levels as an example of how a popular logging library handles this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan#levels

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming the browser and you want a quick and dirty global variable, you can do `window.myVar = 'whatever'`.